# I don't understand to use `case` in `if()` statment in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm new in Dart and I don't understand `case` in `if()` statatement how it work?

```
TreeSearchResult<Node>? filter;

if (filter case TreeSearchResult<Node> filter?) {
       return node.children.where(filter.hasMatch);
}
```

full source code: [github](https://github.com/baumths/flutter_tree_view/blob/main/example/lib/src/examples/filterable.dart)

Can you help me understand that? What is it used for? Or is there an example that can help me understand it better?

Comment: You may want to check out [the official documentation on this matter](https://dart.dev/language/branches#if-case)

Comment: What @mousetail says: The official documentation for `if`/`case`, and the official documentation for [patterns](https://dart.dev/language/patterns), because an `if (e case pattern) s1; else s2;` is basically the same as a `switch (e) { case pattern: s1; default: s2; }`, so you just need to understand patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` is used for conditional execution of code when we want to execute some code when some conditions are satisfied we write the condition inside `()` of the `if()` and then the code to be executed should be write inside the body of the if statement `{}`.

The breakdown of your code is

```dart
if (filter case TreeSearchResult<Node> filter?) { 
       return node.children.where(filter.hasMatch);
}
```

if `(filter case TreeSearchResult<Node> filter?)` condition is stratified. This line checks if the `filter` is of type `TreeSearchResult<Node>` and the '?' and the end check that it is not `null`. If it is, the subsequent block of code will execute.

read more about [if-case](https://dart.dev/language/branches#if-case)

Comment: What does the `?` at the end mean in this case?

Comment: ? operator in dart is used for nullablity

Comment: I understand that but it doesn't make sense in this case. `filter` is already either a `TreeSearchResult` or `null` so it seems like it's negating the entire point of the if statement?

Comment: in this case it is checking the nullability that the filter is not null.
check the code for demo here
https://gist.github.com/Munsif-Ali/d2cc7d13efb1e9203d0ccfbf988c50a2

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class Shape {}

class Circle extends Shape {
  final double radius;
  Circle(this.radius);
}

class Square extends Shape {
  final double side;
  Square(this.side);
}

double calculateArea(Shape shape) {
  if (shape case Circle circle) {
    return circle.radius * circle.radius * 3.14159;
  } else if (shape case Square square) {
    return square.side * square.side;
  } else {
    throw ArgumentError("Unknown shape");
  }
}

void main() {
  Shape circle = Circle(5.0);
  Shape square = Square(4.0);

  print("Area of the circle: ${calculateArea(circle)}"); // Output: Area of the circle: 78.53975
  print("Area of the square: ${calculateArea(square)}"); // Output: Area of the square: 16.0
}
```

In this situation, we create a framework for representing shapes using a class called Shape. We then create two types of shapes: circles and squares, each with their own unique properties like radius and side length. Next, we write a function called calculateArea that takes a shape as input and calculates its area. To do this, the function checks the type of shape using a method called pattern matching. If the shape is recognized as a circle or square, the function calculates its area accordingly. However, if the shape is neither a circle nor a square, the function throws an error to alert the user.

Comment: I'd flag this code in a review.  You're making a switch-case, but without being able to leverage exhaustibility.  Just use a switch-case!